# How to run javascript script in windows8.0?the default program for js file in my PC was changed to be word

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

I got a js file to do something automatically.
But the default program in my PC to run js file is Word.
There seems to be no available program in my *open with..* list

How can I run this type of file?

Comment: drag and drop into your favorite text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Open with --> Microsoft Windows Based Script Host` if available or browse to `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe` in System 32 folder manually whereas cscript.exe is used for console applications and wscript.exe for windows applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using these options. open the CMD (or Command Prompt) and type this

```
Cscript.exe "FileName.js"
```

or

```
Wscript.exe "FileName.js"
```

More info? Read the Microsoft
[Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wsh_runfromcommandprompt.mspx?mfr=true)